# Pop!_OS: I can't print from any browser but i can print from local apps

Tags: printing

this is my first post and the reason is because i have one week since i installed Linux on my laptop but i have a problem with my printer it doesn't work with any browser or the app document viewer from gnome but it works perfectly with terminal or LibreOffice apps. Sorry for my English but I'm not a native speaker, i would be very grateful if you could help me.
My printer is a EPSON L475 and i have POP_OS! as my personal distro also it uses CUPS to control the printer functions from Linux.

Comment: Unfortunately, POP_OS is off topic here.

Comment: This is not about Ubuntu. Pop!_OS is not Ubuntu. It's off topic here per http://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic "Questions that you should avoid: Linux Mint, Elementary OS, Backtrack, Gnome-Remix (prior to 13.04), budgie-remix (16.04 & 16.10) & other Linux distributions" There are significant differences between Ubuntu & Pop!_OS. Until you install 100% std. Ubuntu or a Ubuntu 'flavour' http://ubuntu.com/download/flavours many folks here would suggest you visit Pop!_OS Support at http://pop.system76.com/docs , http://reddit.com/r/pop_os , chat.pop-os.org, or http://unix.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm very  happy and proud to say that i could resolve my problem by myself yeah it's just a printer installation but since I'm a noob linux user I'm happy so I would like to share my solution with you all and hope that in the future someone can benefit from me in the same way that I have benefited from a lot of posts. What i did was search the driver from [this link when you can obtain drivers and manuals for any Epson Product](http://download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/search/01/search/?OSC=LX). Then I read a manual there where it says that is better to use a PPD file instead of manually selecting the driver from [Cups](http://localhost:631/) which is the default utility to manage printers in most of the recent Linux distributions so probably you also use it. You can find the PPD file on your computer when you have correctly installed the correct driver for your printer . Probably the PPD file is in this directory of your computer:

> /opt/"name of your driver"/ppds/"brand of your printer"/"model of your printer"

Once you have correctly selected the PPD file you just have to press continue and let Cups get installed your printer for you.

[When you enter Cups select administration and add printer the first time you have to enter root as id or username and your administrator password](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PHGeU.png)
[select your printer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/78dYk.png)
[just press continue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j3Tu4.png)
[browse your PPD file[6](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aHTLb.png)
[browse according to the directory i wrote][7](https://i.stack.imgur.com/og3Uh.png)
[Just press add printer and set the default printing options][8](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bt44d.png)